# How to query messages by time in a Redis database?

Tags: redis

I've been searching for this specific use case and couldn't find an answer for it.

I have millions of incoming messages per day of this form:

```
{ time: <time in ms>, data: <bytes> }
```

where, `time` is a unique value in milliseconds and `data` consists of 8 bytes.

I need to be able to query the data by time. Now I'm using MongoDB with Node.js.

Will Redis be more suitable for this task? And what data structures and commands are required?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the [Sorted Set commands](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set), ZADD and ZRANGEBYSCORE.

Comment: I'll look it up, thanks for the pointer!